# Как сделать такую навигацию по шагам в линию?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Как можно сделать такую навигацию меню по шагам в линию? Спасибо за помощь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попытки хоть и провальные где?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav>ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav>ul li:hover,
.nav>ul li .active {
  border-bottom: 8px solid red;
}

.nav>ul li .num {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.nav>ul li:hover .num,
.nav>ul li .active .num {
  top: 1px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background: red;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.nav>ul li .title {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.nav>ul li:hover .title,
.nav>ul li .active .title {
  top: -30px;
  color: red;
}

.nav>ul li,
.nav>ul li .num,
.nav>ul li .title {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="num">1</span><span class="title">Один</span></li>
    <li><span class="num">2</span><span class="title">Два</span></li>
    <li><span class="num">3</span><span class="title">Три</span></li>
    <li><span class="num">4</span><span class="title">Четыре</span></li>
    <li><span class="num">5</span><span class="title">Пять</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Справедливость восстановлена! ;)